# What is the use case of pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm reading about this new shiny tool called `pipenv` and can't understand what is the use case of this tool.

1. To create a package I still need to maintain `setup.py` and `requirements.txt`.
2. To create development environments I most likely still need `tox` and `virtualenv`.
3. To create packages or wheels I still need to use `pip`, because [pipenv devs don't care about this feature](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1593)

So what's the point of yet another tool and config files with different syntax? What problem does `pipenv` solve?

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, but just wanted to say: I also find this project superfluous.

Comment: `requirements.txt`, at least, can be generated by `pipenv` from the `Pipfile`. `virutalenv` is still used, but by `pipenv`, not you directly.

Comment: For point three… I don’t think you can create packages with pip? You’d need setuptools for that.

Comment: Pipenv does not cover any of the features you mentioned, so I guess the answer is *There is not a use case of Pipenv in your workflow*. There is for some people’s workflows, but not yours. Feel free to not use it; it is by no means mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the functions of `setup.py`, `tox`, `requirements`, `virtualenv`, etc. are critical for someone distributing a library that needs to be built and tested against multiple versions of Python and possibly multiple versions of their requirements.

The [docs mention this](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#pipfile-vs-setuppy), but I'll reiterate. Pipenv is aimed at application developers and service providers. In those cases, you're typically building a single configuration, and your aggressively updating your version set. In addition, you need to be able to roll back easily to a prior version set.

What you got with `requirements.txt` was version pinning, so you could roll back, but pip never enforced version consistency, so you could construct a `requirements.txt` that had contradictory versions. It's python, so most of the time you can get away with it, but having consistent versions does mitigate that class of problems.

[pip-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/) can construct consistent version sets, but you're now dealing with three separate utilities: `pip`, `pip-tools` and `virtualenv`. This is great if everyone is always careful to run all three to keep things up to date, and of course they don't.

What pipenv adds is combining the management of all three of those and enforcing version consistency at all times.

If you do something as simple as `git checkout`, all you have to do is run `pipenv sync --dev` to update your virtualenv.

With pip, you'd have to blow away the virtualenv entirely and rerun `pip install` as pip won't remove existing packages.

If you set up your Pipfile to have `"yourpackage" = {path=".", editable=true}`, then you can update a requirement in `setup.py` and `pipenv update` will ensure your virtualenv is updated accordingly, or report an error.

To be clear, there is no use case that is handled by pipenv alone; you can do it with other tools. But it does have an audience in mind, application developers, and it is differentiated by providing a much more consistent experience for users. I've also found that, in practice, it's quite helpful for library development too, as a test suite is an application in itself.